# Security testing for iOS app

Tags: security-testing, ios

I got task today to do security testing of an iOS app. I have read many articles and answers on google search and in this site. But still, none provide exact tricks for security testing of an iOS app.

Can anyone help? I would like to know the following :

1 - How to check sql injection in an iOS app.

2 - How to check XSS in an iOS app.

3 - How can I make sure that data transfer between user and database is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find OWASP to be a great resource for security/penetration testing. Start [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Application_Security_Testing_Cheat_Sheet) for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is now also the [OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide (MSTG)](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg), an essential reference for security testing of mobile apps, including iOS and android apps.

> The MSTG is a comprehensive manual for mobile app security testing and reverse engineering. It describes technical processes for verifying the controls listed in the OWASP Mobile Application Verification Standard (MASVS). You can also read the MSTG on Gitbook or download it as an e-book

Answer (score 0):

There are special services that can help in software security testing. They specialize not only in software testing but also in app and website security testing. It is important because most apps are very vulnerable to hacking attacks

Answer (score 0):

I also have heard about security testing services. But it is rather difficult to find a good one. On the Net I've found a good compilation of testing tools - https://qawerk.com/blog/top-10-open-source-software-security-testing-tools/.I tried some of them and I can say that they were really effecient. I've found some errors in my software and, fortunately, I have done it before releasing the product. So I'm really satisfied with these tools and you can try

Comment: Welcome to the community. Just giving links is usually frowned upon because they can go stale. Can you sumerize the list or give details on what these tools do? Also see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer